# Ampliar tamaño ejes en figuras matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, plot

utilizo matplotlib para pilotear gráficas en python. siempre obtengo un tamaño muy pequeño de las escalas de los ejes x,y. Quisiera saber como puedo ampliar el tamaño de las unidles y la leyenda para cada eje sin tener que ampliar la imagen. Os adjunto un ejemplo de gráfica. Apenas se puede leer los números de los ejes y su descripción. Tampoco puedo ampliar el título. Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya que la fuente tipográfica tiene un tamaño en puntos prefijado, la opción más sencilla es reducir el tamaño da la figura completa. Es decir, que en lugar de medir 13 pulgadas de ancho mida por ejemplo 6 pulgadas. De ese modo el texto parecerá el doble de grande. Aumenta la resolución al exportarlo como PNG para que se siga viendo del mismo tamaño en píxeles.

Answer (score 0):

Pasa como parámetro en tu plot figsize de esta manera:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
```